# How to find list of IDs in a text in R

Tags: r

Here's my case. I have a df with text rows and a df with IDs. I want to know if the IDs appear in my text. Here's my code – do I overlook s.th.?

```
df <- data.frame(text=c("random text with ID _OMaUIC4Om", 
                        "random text with ID  _tqlb6VsVN",
                        "random text with ID  0AcMp9JJ8q",
                        "random text with ID  _tqlb6VsVN",
                        "random text with ID  _tqlb6VsVN",
                        "random text with ID"))


df.id <- data.frame(id=c("_4pGCmTAat","_tqlb6VsVN","_OMaUIC4Om","0AcMp9JJ8q"))


check <- subset(df, text %in% df.id$id)
check <- subset(df, grep(df.id$id, text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` them and pass into `grepl`

```
subset(df, grepl(paste(df.id$id, collapse="|"), text))
```

-output

```
#                              text
#1  random text with ID _OMaUIC4Om
#2 random text with ID  _tqlb6VsVN
#3 random text with ID  0AcMp9JJ8q
#4 random text with ID  _tqlb6VsVN
#5 random text with ID  _tqlb6VsVN
```

Comment: I will. Hit the button but must wait 10 minutes. I will not forget it.